# Angular loading images from a ng-view file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat

I have a single page app.(index.html). The relevant parts are given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/mi_ui/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
...
<body ng-app="sk" ng-controller="mainController as main">
<div ng-view></div>
```

The route file relevant parts:

```
.when('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'home',
    })
```

My code is in a folder named as mi_ui. Only the base href path i set above works. All other values like (/) will not load the resources.

My Folder structure is:

```
mi_ui
--assets
----css
----js
----images
------loader.gif
--services
--controllers
--views
----home.html
app.js
index.html
```

The above application works flawlessly. Issue is, i want to load the loader.gif in home.html. I put the below code:

```
<img ng-src="assets/images/loader.gif" id="gif">
```

But this image is not loaded. **From Chrome developer console i saw that sources tab only have files that are referenced in index.html!**. So if i put the img line in index.html ,the file is loaded and is shown in Chrome sources tab. But not from home.html. Any idea how to fix this?

I am running the app in tomcat 7.

Comment: use `src` insteed of `ng-src`, `ng-src` use for scope variable only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `ng-src` with `src`

```
<img src="assets/images/loader.gif" id="gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

clear browser history and try again.